# Javascript background fixed size

Tags: javascript, background-image, autoresize, window-resize

Hello i am still in the process of learning and i have a question : 
I am trying to make a webpage but have little knowledge of javascript and i am trying to make a random image change background but to images to be fixed on the screen(as in to be seen all the picture regardless of the browser size)
Hope i am clear enough... but here is the code i used for random background image so far and if someone can help me to resize the image please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var totalCount = 2;
function ChangeIt()
{
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    document.body.background = 'images/'+num+'.jpg';
    document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please bare in mind that background-size is not supported by some older browser

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call your function. Add `ChangeIt();` below your function definition.

Otherwise, your code worked for me on IE8 (Wow!), FF 12, and Chrome 25 on Windows 7.